# Where can I find a good source of information on the material properties of space suit fabrics?

Tags: spacesuits

I'm looking for very detailed information. I read journal articles on a regular basis, so don't pull any punches.

Answer (score 2):

Much of NASA's research is accessible via https://ntrs.nasa.gov/. A search for '[Apollo spacesuit material](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/?N=0&Ntk=All&Ntt=apollo%20spacesuit%20material&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial)' has more than 1000 matches, so have fun!

Comment: This is a minor step up from 'google it'.

Comment: True, but it's the best answer I can give without doing the search for you.